# CSS state will be saved after going back to previous page in FireFox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I found a difference of my website between Chrome (or IE) and Firefox.
Given a simple example,

```
<style>
.showDiv {
    display: block;
}
.hideDiv {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayDiv() {
        $('#div_1').removeClass("hideDiv");
        $('#div_1').addClass("showDiv");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li id="div_0" onclick="displayDiv();">Div
            <div id="div_1" class="hideDiv">
                <a href="test2.html">subDiv</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Clicking on div_0, it shows div_1. Then I click the link in div_1 to redirect to another page. If I go back to previous page, the CSS style of div_1 remains in Firefox but Chrome. Could anyone tell what is the reason for this? Also, how can I modify my code to unify the behavior of two browsers (e.g. let Chrome to keep the CSS style OR let Firefox to renew the CSS style for previous page)?

Here are the result of going back to previous page after redirecting to test2.html.

For Chrome
[image: For Chrome]
For FireFox
[image: For Firefox]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. Hide the subdiv once it is clicked

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/Lyahfjwe/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li id="div_0" onclick="displayDiv()">Div
        <div id="div_1" onclick="hideDiv()" class="hideDiv"> <a href="test2.html">subDiv</a>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
 function displayDiv() {
        $('#div_1').removeClass("hideDiv");
        $('#div_1').addClass("showDiv");
    }

    function hideDiv() {
        $('#div_1').removeClass("showDiv");
        $('#div_1').addClass("hideDiv");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my application takes time to redirect to another page, so user will find it strange when they click on the link and the div hides immediately.

Comment: You can simple set some timeout function so it won't disappear immediately http://jsfiddle.net/Lyahfjwe/1/